# Quickbook Online API throws Error Parsing query / trying to use CASE statement in SQL query

Tags: api, quickbooks

I am trying to get status based to totalamount field.For that I need to use CASE statement like this :

```
Select TotalAmt,CASE WHEN 'TotalAmt' = '0' THEN 'Open' ELSE NULL END AS status from Invoice
```

I have checked the syntax too,it's correct.But still I am getting query Parser error

Answer (score 0):

Intuit's flavor of SQL (which is a very limited, slightly non-SQL-standard dialect of SQL) does not support `CASE` statements.

You can't do what you're trying to do, as it's unsupported.

Comment: Is there any other way through which I can achieve this?

Comment: Look up IF/ELSE statements in whatever programming language you're using. Put the IF/ELSE in your code, instead of in the query.